# How do I render my element using v-show correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2

I have a carousel which only shows when a user opens my accordion menu.

I am using `v-show` to hide the carousel until it's opened. However, it doesn't render the carousel correctly unless I resize the browser window, the first slide shows but to click through the other slides don't show up.

Web inspect shows on load the `translate: transform()` empty for slides until the browser window is resized.

I think this is something to do with `v-show` and how it renders in the DOM, I have seen people using `.$nextTick` or `.$watch` to fix similar issues but I don't understand them enough to apply them to my code.

Is there a way for me to solve this issue using v-show with `.nextTick()` or `.watch()`?

```js
<div :key="project.id">
  <!-- project header -->
  <li
    class="project accordion columns is-flex vcenter"
    @click="toggleItem"
    style="margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;"
  >
    <h3 class="project-title column is-one-quarter">{{ project.Name }}</h3>
    <h4 class="project-summary column is-two-thirds">
      {{ project.Summary }}
    </h4>
    <span class="column is-one-half is-gapless project-icon">
    <img
      src="../static/SVG/Circle.svg"
      alt="circle icon for branding & identity"
    />
  </span>
</li>
```

My hidden content is here, it only shows when the accordion is open using `v-show`.

```js
<div class="showcase-content columns" v-show="show">
  <p class="project-description column is-one-third">
    {{ project.Description }}
  </p>
  <agile :fade="true">
    <div
      class="image-box column is-two-thirds"
      v-for="image in project.image"
      :key="image.url"
    >
      <img :src="buildImageUrl(image.url)" alt="" />
    </div>
  </agile>
</div>
```

**EDIT** I was originally injecting some my accordion in and have refactored the accordion and my code, on the suspicion that injection might not be reactive but the same issue persists. The code on this question is my current code.

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ProjectItem',
  data: function () {
    return {
      show: false,
    }
  },
  props: ['project'],
  methods: {
    toggleItem: function () {
      this.show = !this.show
    },
    buildImageUrl(image) {
      if (!image) return '../static/images/SamB.png'
      return `http://localhost:1337${image}`
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't render the carousel correctly" – in what way?

Comment: The first slide appears normal, but on click through the second slide appears out of position, half off the screen and then each other slides appears empty if I keep clicking through. I used web inspect and it seems Translate is 0/empty until I resize the browser window and then all slides appear as normal during click through .

Comment: Should "is-one-quarter", "is-two-thirds", and "is-one-half" add up to a full width?

Comment: I don't think that's an issue, my understanding is those class names define the width of the column within it's container. After using "is-one-quarter" for a div, when declaring "is-two-thirds" for another it will use two thirds of the remaining space, and then "is-half", uses half of the leftover space. I could be wrong though as I'm new to the Bulma framework too.

Comment: Your question is not answerable without a [mcve]. You have to at least indicate the exact carousel library used and to provide means of testing any potential solution.

Comment: Thanks, I am using vue-agile for the carousel. I will try get a codesandbox.io set up in the morning, I had tried before I posted the question originally but couldn't figure it out

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mclean-2pg64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: leaving this part of the answer in as it might be useful for anyone with a similar problem. However, it was added when the question didn't specify the slider library. To read the actual answer, skip to after the separator*.

- Using `v-show` means the carousel is rendered with `display: none`
- most carousels are setting the size of their slides when they are `init`-ed and they update on `window.resize`

Which means your carousel is `init`-ing with a height of `0`. And it only readjusts on `window.resize`, regardless of the change to the `display` property of your `v-show` element.

A quick and dirty fix is to trigger `window.resize` when the property controlling `v-show` changes. I.e:

```
toggleItem: function () {
  this.show = !this.show;
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
},
```

But ***it's dirty*** and it might also be expensive, depending on what other components/libraries are listening to `resize`.

A much better solution is to call whatever `update` method your carousel library exposes when the `v-show` condition changes.
If you can't figure out how to do that, I suggest adding the carousel library (with version) to the question.

Another potential problem is if the container of the carousel is animated (i.e: you use some type of transition on it). In which case you need to trigger `window.resize`/`carousel.update` at the end of the animation, when the container has the correct size. Which is why it would have been ideal to provide a [minmal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
A(nother) quick and dirty solution for that problem would be to add a `transitionend` listener on the animated element and dispatch `window.resize` in that callback, in which case you no longer need anything else. Also, I'd actually place a check on the `v-show` condition and only dispatch `window.resize` when it's `true`. But, again, it's not really clean and it could have side-effects.

---

**Edit**: since you use `vue-agile`, here's your question answered [in documentation](https://github.com/lukaszflorczak/vue-agile#v-if--v-show):

> It is also possible to use `v-show`, but you have to use the `reload()` method.

Which means this should do it:

```
<template>
   <agile ref="slider" ... />
</template>
```

...

```
methods: {
  toggleItem: function () {
    this.show = !this.show;
    this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.slider.reload());
  }
  ...
}
```

A working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mclean-2pg64?file=/src/components/CollapsedAgileCarousel.vue).

---

**Note**: Replacing `v-show` with `v-if` is an expensive solution, as it means your carousel is added and removed from DOM each time the condition changes. Each time it will rebuild itself and reload the slider images. That's worse than `v-show` + `window.resize` solution.

**Note**: you might want to have a look at the [vue wrapper for Swiper](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper), as (arguably) Swiper is better than Slick.

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks very much for taking the time to set up the codebox example and explain indepth what was happening and why it wasn't working. I really appreciate the help and hope you have a good weekend!